# Alternative virtual machine to run Ubuntu on Mac OS as Virtual box is giving issues?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, mac

Can Ubuntu run on a Virtual Machine? I want to run Ubuntu on a virtual machine since I don't have spare PC's or laptops to install Ubuntu. The problem arises when I try to use VMware or virtual box on a mac os device. Please suggest alternatives on what is the best VM software for mac.

Comment: Virtual Box is the easiest to setup and Ubuntu will certainly work.

Comment: Basically Oracle VM is the way to go, there should not be any issues.
Here is the link where you can download the latest version:

https://www.oracle.com/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/virtualbox-downloads.html

I assume you have the same issues that most people have when trying to run an OS through a VM application inside a working operating system and that would be not assigning enough RAM and CPU power to it or assing too much so that the base hypervisor can not function properly.

Basically you can access the RAM allocation and CPU settings in the Settings>System of any OS